# Writing a query that will handle three different labels

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have 3 different drop down options. If I select one option at a time it works, but on selecting more than one it will throw an error. The three labels refer to three different versions. Everything works but when I select more than one option in the drop down it crashes. Need help understanding it why

The three parameters are 
Select all:
Report1
Report2
Report3

Here my query:

```
SELECT
  ServerInfo.Version,
  ServerInfo.Type,
  ProjInfo.ProjName,
  ServerInfo.ServName
FROM
  ProjInfo, ServerInfo
WHERE ServerInfo.Version LIKE('%'+@ServerReport+'%')
```

---

### Incorrect syntax near ','.

### Query execution failed for dataset 'Report'. (rsErrorExecutingCommand)

An error has occurred during report processing. (rsProcessingAborted)

Comment: Is the issues has to do with casting? Or should I write down individual cases statements for each of the label options ?

Comment: Please provide more info, what are the three labels values?  What variable does it populate, ServerReport?  What is the value of that variable when you select 1 or more option?

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that the query is expecting a single string value, but the report is sending it an array of values when there are multiples selected.

1. In the parameter tab of your dataset properties, update the expression like this:

   `="," & Join(Parameters!ServerReport.Value, ",") & ","`

   This will combine the selected values into a single, comma-separated string.
2. Update your `WHERE` clause like this:

   `@ServerReport like '%,' + ServerInfo.Version + ',%'`

This allows it to scan for the version string in the parameter string. The commas on the outside of both the joined parameter and the `like` statement prevent it from inadvertently matching partial strings.

**Clarification:**
This is all assuming that you actually need the `like` statement in the first place. Normally you would just say:

```
ServerInfo.Version IN (@ServerReport)
```

This would accept multiple values without any other changes. But the strings would have to be an exact match.

Comment: The three labels that I have in ServerReport are  Report1 Report2 Report3. Report 1 is set to 10 , Report2 is 13 , and Report3 is set to 14. Since there are three different version in the database, that start with these three values. Version are set like 10.12.12 for example. That why I was using Like condition

Comment: I try this solution but it doesn't populate any results at all. Do I need to use a case condition for each of the report values?

Comment: If you search for Report 1 (10), won't it return results like 9.10, 10.10, 13.10, and 14.10 ? What is your intended result?

Comment: My intended result should be: Report1(label value is set to 10). It should display version results that start with 10. for example 10.20.10 , 10.34.10. I'm basically trying to do a comparison if Report1 is selected display all the results that start with 10. If report2 is selected display all the results with 13

Comment: OK, set your `WHERE` clause like this to search the first set of digits in the version number: `@ServerReport like '%' + LEFT(ServerInfo.Version, CHARINDEX('.', ServerInfo.Version) - 1) + '%'`

Comment: The following errors keeps coming on not sure what exactly is wrong with it. ---------------------------------------------------------------------                                                                                                          An error occurred while reading data from the query result set.
Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function. (Microsoft SQL Server Report Builder)

===================================

Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function. (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)

Comment: So you have some version numbers with no "." in them. You can add a case statement to handle those cases: `case when CHARINDEX('.', ServerInfo.Version) > 0 then 
@ServerReport like '%' + LEFT(ServerInfo.Version + , CHARINDEX('.', ServerInfo.Version) - 1) + '%'
else @ServerReport like '%' + ServerInfo.Version + '%' end`

Comment: Edit your question to show some sample data. It will be easier to understand. I suspect there will be a simple way of solving this.